# How to resolve Polyfill node core modules error in webpack 5

Tags: reactjs, next.js, error-handling

I am currently working on an e-commerce React app. I run the admin panel in my system I encountered the following error.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/bloom-filter/base-filter.js 39:11-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\yolo\yolo-admin\backend\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\bloom-filter'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

But I run this same admin panel code in another system, it is working fine. I dont know whether it may be any software needed or have to do any software setup has to be done. Because this is a new system.

I need to resolve this error. Recently I installed Python and visual studio(Development environment C++). I think all the software I have to run this project.

As mentioned in error, I installed "crypto-broswerify" and add the below code in next.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // Other webpack configuration options...

  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
    },
  },
};
```